# How can you return an integer if a certain condition is met in SQL?

Tags: sql

Suppose I want to return the number '1' if EXISTS (customers.salary>'1000')

I tried:

```
SELECT 1
FROM customers
WHERE EXISTS (customers.salary>'1000')
```

also this could work:

```
SELECT COUNT(salary)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(salary) FROM (SELECT salary FROM costomers WHERE salary>'1000'));
```

but what if I would like to return some other number not 1?

Comment: @AhmadSaleh To return the number 1 on a single line if the condition is met. The first example should work? I tried an online compiler and it didn't. I   had this question asked at an interview.

Comment: Which database are you looking for and where did you try online?

Comment: @LearningNeverStops I tried on www.w3schools.com and that was a random example. I don't need this for a specific database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT
     CASE WHEN (customers.salary>1000) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS overThousand
 FROM customers
```

Will bring back a 1 for each row where salary is over 1000. So if you also took your customer name, your results woul be "bob, 1" (Salary over 1000), "Dave, 0" (Salary under 1000).

If you literally just want a '1' if there is a salary over 1000 anywhere in the customer table, the following is my suggestion:

```
  SELECT 1
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT c.salary FROM customers c WHERE c.salary > 1000)
```

- You don't need FROM customers in your main statement
- You need a full statement in your EXISTS. (SELECT, FROM, WHERE)
- Using apostrophes around your '1000' wont work. You need it to be recognised as a number to use the > operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can return any number of your choice through your first query, or even an expression.

```
SELECT 10
FROM customers
WHERE EXISTS (customers.salary>'1000')
```

You can check the syntax of [SELECT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2065706) statement for more on this, and then read through the [SQL expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions001.htm#i1002626) on Oracle documentation, for more details.

Edit:
To clarify, this answer applies to Oracle database, even though you are not concerned about databases while looking for an answer.

Comment: Ok, so I understand this should actually work. Good, more elegant than my SELECT COUNT( ....

Answer (score 0):

Following up on your comments, The following will work for `T-SQL`.
It will Return `1` if a salary greater than 1000 exists, and `NULL` if not:

```
SELECT MAX(1)
FROM customers
WHERE  salary>1000
```